# how to create and save a pycharm project from an existing python program?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I recently installed TensorFlow on a Ubunu 14.04 machine using virtual environment and installed PyCharm to analyze TensoFlow Python programs.

I downloaded `mnist_softmax.py`, the first tutorial program under `~/TF`. I opened it with PyCharm and set the Python interpreter to the one in the virtual environment. I can run it, set breakpoint, and do single stepping.

Ok, then,  I exit PyCharm . When I start PyCharm again, the recent project list is shown, but the location is `/tmp/mnist_softmax.py`, not `~/TF/mnist_softmax.py` and of course if I try to open it (`/tmp/mnist_softmax.py`), it complains that the file is not there.

How can I save the `mnist_softmax.py` as a PyCharm project? I couldn't find the submenu in the `File` menu. I tried `Save All` before exiting but it was the same and no `*.idea` file is under `~/TF`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found creating a project and adding the source file makes pychamr remember the project as working previous project in the list.